# How do I find relevance between documents while creating multi-document summary?

Tags: data-mining, information-retrieval

I want to generate a multi-document summary. I have already generated single document summary of each document. In some research papers, a multi-document summary is generated by making single document by appending each input document into it and then generate a single document summary. I have done it by combining summary of each input document. but, I am not satisfied. I am following the traditional approach to finding out the relevance between a summary of each document i.e. TF-IDF. Am I working correctly? Or should I follow different approach?